# Use the same piece of code without using macros for two different data types

Tags: c++

I want to use a single piece of code for two different data types without using macros. I tried something like this, but I did not come up with a complete solution.

```
void func(bool istype1, void *ptr)
{
    void *t1;
    if(isType1)
        t1=static_cast<type1>(ptr);
    else   // isType1 == false means data type 2.
        t1=static_cast<type2>(ptr);

    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you assign the casted pointer back to a `void *`, you are immediately discarding the type information again.

Comment: How you do this depends *entirely* on what is in those `...`s and what exactly you want to do with the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a template.  You'll have to read up on them somewhere.  http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

You can implement a max like

```
template <class T>
T max(T one, T two)
{
   return one > two ? one : two;
}
```

This will work on any object where you can compare the classes.  Ints, floats, and even use defined classes.